# xcode 5.0.2 but no iOS 7.0.4?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have Xcode 5.0.2 but somehow I don't have iOS 7.0.4 in the simulator.

I did not find any updates and it looks like everything is up to date.

Who do I get to debug a iPhone with iOS 7.0.4 in the simulator?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, exactly. What is the problem you're having?

Comment: @JamesFrost I made an update. Basically I want `iOS 7.0.4` in the emulator.

Comment: Did you try to look at XCode settings -> Downloads? Usually you can install different iOS Simulator versions there. P.S. However, in my case I have iOS 7 simulator, but it is not listed in Downloads.

Comment: @FreeNickname Yes, I did check that but it looks to me like you only getting older versions from there. It shows iOs 6.0 and 6.1 for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this image would solve all your queries.
[image]

Image Source:- https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action (require login).
In short, **Xcode 5.0.2 comes with support of iOS 7.0.3(or below)**.
**Note:-** In iOS, we have Simulator, not emulator. Emulator is for Android.

Comment: So there is just no 7.0.4 and I don't need to worry about it yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simulator is not that granular when it comes to iOS versions as far as I've been able to tell. You shouldn't depend on it behaving properly anyhow, it is very different from devices in a lot of senses.

Comment: I think, what PiTheNumber is trying to tell is that he just doesn't have an iOS 7.0.4 in his simulator, despite the fact that he has installed all available updates.

Comment: yes, but 7.0.4 did not come with a new SDK, probably because the only official fix for it was some FaceTime issue.

Comment: So there is just no `7.0.4` and I don't need to worry about it because there are only minor modifications anyway?

Comment: as far as I know, yes. Also from iOS 6.x I can't remember every minos iOS version being accompanied by a Xcode release, but my memory might just be failing me.